How to write a C program that makes a bell sound many time in succession?
I have a C program , running on a Linux system, that can take up to a hour to complete. I need to monitor it's behavior at various times, from other processes, for example perf. The program prints out various diagnostics so if I watch it I'll know exactly when to run my observability tools.
But I don't want to spend time watching the program waiting for it to get to the proper places where I need to take action, since I have other things to do. So it seemed like a solution to my problem was to have the program make sounds when it gets to places where I need to take action. Having it ring the bell would do the job. However I could very easily miss a single ring of the bell, so I would like to make the bell ring 30 or 40 times in succession.
The problem is that if I write the following loop:
for ( i=0; i<40; i++)
   {
      printf("\a");
   }

the bell only rings once. Even if I manually inline the printf()s, and insert statements between each one, the bell still only rings once.
Maybe the optimizer optimizes away the additional beeps; I didn't check the generated assembly to see if this is the case. But this is doubtful, because if I change the printf()s to
printf("----------------------- \a \n");

I get as many lines of dashes, as I ask for, but still only one bell beep.
So, is there a way to get 40 beeps in succession?

You can always use the curses.h/ncurses.h beep() function. Otherwise you will likely need to find the pc speaker hardware address and use an inline assembly hack to make it beep. You can try adding a fflush(); usleep(100000); after your printf() and put a .1 sec delay in the loop. (#include <unistd.h> for usleep()) The fflush() prevents stdout from buffering your output.

I just tried puts ("\a"); usleep (100000); in a loop 40 times and it worked fine. (note: puts() just adds a '\n' negating the need for fflush() to prevent buffering)

Or, for fun puts ("\a\x1B[1A"); to avoid the newline output \x1B[1A (or \033[1A) is just an ANSI escape to move up 1 line. An equivalent would be your printf ("\a") or putchar ('\a') or fputs ("\a", stdout) -- then the fflush (stdout). All variations do the same thing.

Always add a delay in between printing \a and a fflush after otherwise you will get one uninterruptable continuous squeal.  I've seen this happen when a Senior Programmer didn't hear any beeps and decided to put in 1000 \a.  It started as a beep and then changed tone and became a squeal.  The code had finished executing but the squeal continued for about 2 minutes and nothing could stop it.

@cup - interesting. I executed exactly as written in the comment and had no issue. Also set the delay at 50 ms (50000 us). You can also directly access the pc speaker to create other tones OSDev PC Speaker. I hadn't found the <sys/io.h> functions before stumbling on that page. Bet your Senior Programmer had a sheepish grin after that one...

OT: Taking the dog for a short walk may cause you to not hear an alert. If the processing time can be estimated, a "progress bar" might enable you to see and to estimate how much time remains until the next "check point". If interested, search [c] "progress bar" for a number of Q&A's here. Good luck...
